# Change color on ggplot2

Tags: r

How to change color on this R code:

```
ggplot(data = melted_cormat, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

i meant, this background colour.

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Change color of what? Tiles, title, background? Please include all external packages that you're using.

Comment: thx. update done.

Comment: You mean from "blue"? To what you want to change it?

Comment: Yes, the same color is a little bit confuse, I want more than one color. Or do you have any suggest? for the viewers to get better visualizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill in the colors you like in `scale_fill_gradientn()`:

```
# sample data
x <- Orange
colnames(x) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "value")

# plot
ggplot(x, aes(x=Var1, y=Var2, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = c("blue", "green", "yellow", "red"))
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: excellent!. That what i want. Thx u @PoGibas